# How Update Fragment ListView From BroadcastReceiver Class

Tags: android

I am working a calling application , in my application i set a alarm task and in broadcastreceiver class after task completed i need to update fragment list view.

my fragment class..

```
 public class CallScheduling extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView messageText;
FloatingActionButton AddScheduleCall;
RecyclerView SheduleCalled;
View view;

DataBase dataBase;
List<SchedueModel> schedueModels;

public CallScheduling() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_call_scheduling, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    init();
    return view;
}

private void init() {

    messageText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.messageText);
    AddScheduleCall = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.AddScheduleCall);
    SheduleCalled = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.SheduleCalled);
    AddScheduleCall.setOnClickListener(this);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    SheduleCalled.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    SheduleCalled.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    dataBase = App.getInstance().getDatBase();
    if (dataBase.checkForTables(Constant.TABLE_SCHEDULING)) {
        messageText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        SheduleCalled.setAdapter(new ScheduleAdapter(getActivity()));
        schedueModels = dataBase.GetAllScheduledCall();

        Collections.sort(schedueModels, new Comparator<SchedueModel>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(SchedueModel schedueModel, SchedueModel t1) {
                return schedueModel.getDate().compareTo(t1.getDate());
            }
        });


        ActiveSchedul();

    } else {

        messageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}

private void ActiveSchedul() {


    for (int i = 0; i < schedueModels.size(); i++) {

        if (schedueModels.get(i).getCompleted().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = sdf.parse(schedueModels.get(0).getDate());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            long startDate = date.getTime();

            Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(getActivity(), SchecduleBroadcast.class);
            intentAlarm.putExtra("data", schedueModels.get(i));
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startDate, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
            break;
        } else {
            boolean deleted = dataBase.deleteUser(schedueModels.get(i).getNumber(), Constant.TABLE_SCHEDULING, Constant.NUMBER);
            if (deleted) {
                schedueModels.remove(i);
                SheduleCalled.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

    }


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.AddScheduleCall:

            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ScheduleForm.class));

            break;

        default:

            break;
    }
}
```

and this is my broadcastreceiver...

```
public class SchecduleBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    SchedueModel schedueModel;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        if (intent.getSerializableExtra("data") != null) {
            schedueModel = (SchedueModel) intent.getSerializableExtra("data");
            Toast.makeText(context, schedueModel.getNumber() + " Is Completed ! Thanx", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            schedueModel.setCompleted("1");
            App.getInstance().getDatBase().updateScheduledCall(schedueModel);
//            new Home().updateFragment(CallScheduling.class, null);


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** An inner BroadcastReceiver class

```
class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Register the receiver

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!receiverResgistered) {
            registerReceiver(myBroadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter("intent.filter.data"));
            receiverResgistered = true;
        }
    }
```

**Step 3:** Unregister Receiver

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (receiverResgistered) {
            unregisterReceiver(myBroadCastReceiver);
            receiverResgistered = false;
        }
    }
```

**Step 4:** Broadcast the data from SchecduleBroadcast

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Intent i = new Intent("intent.filter.data");
i.putExtras(bundle);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

**OR**

You can make `SchecduleBroadcast` inner class of the fragment

Answer (score 0):

you need to register a `LocalBroadcast` in your Fragment, and call your update method in `onReceive`